# How i can copy file from server(OS:ubuntu 10.04) to my PC(OS:windows 7)?

Tags: linux, file-sharing, ubuntu-10.04, linux-server

How i can copy file from server(OS:ubuntu 10.04) to local HDD in my PC(OS:windows 7) ??

note :- if you can help me by give me the command which copy file from server to my pc (becouse i enter to server remotly)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One out of many ways: Install SSH on the Ubuntu machine and use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) on Windows.

**Addendum:**

If you insist on the command line and have putty installed, use pscp.exe like this:

`pscp remoteuser@remotehost.com:/remotepath/remotefile.doc localfilename.doc`

(See the [doc](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter5.html#pscp))

Comment: if you can help me by give me the command which copy file from server to my pc (becouse i enter to server remotly)

Comment: You most likely connect to the server with SSH (like putty), right? WinSCP is just another way to access the server via the SSH protocol, but here you don't enter commands but see the remote filesystem of the server on your local machine and can copy files this way.

Comment: pleas i want to ask you this command can transfer file from serve to HDD in my PC (dor example put it in D:/)

Comment: please the case as the follwing i make a backup to x folder and i want to copy it from server to my PC

Comment: Read the documentation I linked. I am not going to repeat it here. Also, you will need to better explain what you want to do in your question. For making backups of more than a few files, I would have recommended rsync. Search here and on superuser for rsync-related questions. I bet you will find detailed instructions on how to use it. 
And last: Your questions is a better fit on superuser.com than here.

Answer (score 1):

From what it sounds like, you're just doing a one off copy, am I right?  Here's what you'll probably want to do.

1. (On Ubuntu) Read about how to setup an SSh server in the [Ubuntu OpenSSH Server wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/openssh-server.html)
2. (On Windows) Use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) to connect to your Ubuntu machine (enter the hostname, your username, and your password)
3. (On Windows) Using the interface, navigate to the file and transfer it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the folder that the file is in shared over CIFS/SMB.  However you have to install Samba, and doing that properly (and securely) can take a little effort.

You could also share it over http with WebDav.  This too would require some effort to configure properly, but you would now be running a Web Server on your network.  This gives you great flexibility, but can come with it's own set of problems.

However, I do recommend running sshd on the server and using PuTTY/pscp (or optionally WinSCP.)

Answer (score 0):

the answer is download the FileZilla program in your PC and login to the server ... then you can copy file from/to your computer

Comment: Only relevant if he has sshd running--which is not the default on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

by far the easiest way is to do a `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888` on the linux and go to url `http://ip.address.of.the.linux.pc:8888` with a web browser on the Windows

No need to install anything extra on either host.